# Proving a map $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is $C^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, locally-convex-spaces, schwartz-space

I am working through Reed and Simon's book on functional analysis. This is one of their exercises:

Let $\mathscr{S}$ denote the space of Schwartz functions, $\mathscr{S}'$ the space of tempered distributions, and $\delta$ the delta function.

> (a) Let $\varphi \in \mathscr{S}$ and let $\varphi_y$ be the function in $\mathscr{S}$ defined by $\varphi_y(x) = \varphi(x-y)$. Prove that the map $y \mapsto \varphi_y$ is a $C^\infty$ function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $D^\alpha(\varphi_y) = (-1)^\alpha(D^\alpha \varphi)_y.$ To say $y \mapsto \varphi_y$ has derivative $\frac{\partial \varphi_y}{\partial y_j}$ as a function with values in $\mathscr{S}$ means $$\lim_{y\rightarrow y_0} |y-y_0|^{-1} \Big[\varphi_y - \varphi_{y_0} - \sum_{j=0}^N \frac\partial{\partial y_j}(\varphi_y) \cdot (y-y_0)_j\Big] = 0$$ in the topology of $\mathscr{S}$.
>
> (b) Let $T \in \mathscr{S}'$. Let $\varphi \in \mathscr{S}$. Define $T^\varphi$ to be the function, $T^\varphi(y) = T(\varphi_y)$. Prove that $T^\varphi \in C^\infty$.
>
> (c) Let $\varphi_n \in \mathscr{S}$ with $\varphi_n \rightarrow \delta$ in the weak topology on $\mathscr{S}'$. Prove that $T^{\varphi_n} \rightarrow T$ for all $T \in \mathscr{S}'$ in the weak topology on $\mathscr{S}'$.
>
> (d) Prove that $\mathscr{S}$ is dense in $\mathscr{S}'$.

I could not find a similar problem so I am having some trouble getting started. I know that $\mathscr{S}$ is generated by the seminorms
$$\|\varphi\|_{\alpha, \beta} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} |x^\alpha D^\beta\varphi(x)|$$
but not much beyond that. I would like to use this exercise as a learning experience for tempered distributions. Any help on how to approach these problems would be much appreciated.

As suggested in the comments, these are the definitions I am using:

- A map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is in $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if $\|f\|_{\alpha, \beta} < \infty$ for all $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (which are $n$-tuples of nonnegative integers).
- A tempered distribution $T \in \mathscr{S}'$ is a continuous linear functional on $\mathscr{S}$. Thus $T$ is continuous if and only if there exists a $i_1, \ldots, i_n$ and constants $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ such that $$\forall f \in \mathscr{S}: \quad |T(f)| \leq \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_{j} \| f \|_{i_{j}}.$$

Comment: I would start with part $a.).$ Think of Taylor's theorem and then ask yourself why the remainder is bounded wrt the seminorms in questions. For $b.)$ I would ask myself how regular the map $\varphi \mapsto T(\varphi)$ is for fixed $T$. That should allow you to get started.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you for your comment. I have tried working on the proofs following your hints. What is causing me some trouble is how to use Taylor's theorem on $y \mapsto \varphi_y$ since the range is a function space and not $\mathbb{R}^n$. For (b), how would we determine the regularity of that map?

Comment: Look at the remainder and use the seminorms (in fact, applying the MWT twice is enough to get a good error term). For $b.),$ the map I mentioned is linear and bounded (by assumption). Now compute the first derivative and then show that the second derivative vanishes.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you for providing more comments. Using Taylor's theorem we can write $\varphi_y$ as a polynomial and a remainder term, all of which are smooth, but how do we know that they decay sufficiently fast? Also doesn't Taylor's theorem assume the image is in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (as opposed to $\mathscr{S}$)? For (b), I assume we are taking the distributional derivative?

Comment: Let's do it for $n=1$. Then $$\varphi_y(x) - \varphi_{y_0}(x)-\partial_y\varphi_y(x)(y-y_0)=\varphi(x-y)-\varphi(x-y_0)+\varphi'(x-y)(y-y_0).$$ By the MVT there exists $\xi_x$ between $x-y$ and $x-y_0$ such that the above expression becomes $$ \varphi'(\xi_x)(y_0-y)+\varphi'(x-y)(y-y_0)=(\varphi'(\xi_x)-\varphi'(x-y))(y-y_0).$$ Using the MVT once more, we can estimate the absolute value of this expression by $$\Vert \varphi''\Vert_\infty \vert y-y_0\vert^2.$$ I leave everything else to you.

Comment: For $b)$ use my previous comment. We have $$T^\varphi(y)-T^\varphi(y_0)-T(\partial_y\varphi_y)=T(\varphi_y-\varphi_{y_0} - \partial_y \varphi_y).$$ Now use that $T$ is continuous and the previous estimate wrt to the second derivative (which is one of the seminorms).

Comment: I strongly suggest that you spell out the definition for $T\in \mathcal{S}'$ and also the other notions you need for the remaining exercises. Most the difficulty arises from not knowing the proper definitions.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you. I have been working on trying to complete everything based on your comments but I am still having trouble. For example, I would have never thought to use the MVT. The definitions I am using is that $f \in \mathscr{S}$ if $\|f\|_{\alpha, \beta}$ for all $\alpha$ and $\beta$. And also that $T \in \mathscr{S}'$ if $T$ is in the topological dual of $\mathscr{S}$, meaning $T$ is linear and continuous (i.e. the operator norm is bounded).

Comment: You should not write it in the comments, but in your post. At the moment it looks like you have put no effort into answering your question. Try to spell out, what it means for $T$ to be continuous in terms of the seminorms. It will be quite instructive.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I'll include the definitions in my question. Maybe I need to continue thinking more about the problem and then I will update my post with what I have tried. Thank you for all your help and patience.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven You were correct about not knowing the proper definitions. While typing up the definitions I realized my definition of $T$ being continuous (bounded so $|T(f)| \leq C \|f\|$) is wrong and only applies to Banach spaces. I have edited my post to include the correct condition for locally convex spaces.